# SQL order by

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

I need to order a table conditioned by date and i cant do it!! :(

i have a field (codigo) that if the year of the date(passed by parameter) is less than 2010 then it is composed like this : "FAC-00123-10", then i nedd to order by this "00123"...

Otherwise, if the year code is bigger than 2010, the field (Codigo) is created like this "FT 11/123" and then i need to order by this "123"

How can i do this?!

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [case when](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258235%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) statement to decide what to order by, this uses a simple substring but in reality this probably isnt good enough and you may need to parse the bit you are interested in a little bit better..

```
select * from table order by 
   case when DatePart(year,@date) < 2010 then substring(codigo,4,5)
        else substring(condigo,3,2) end
```

Comment: The comparison should be `<= 2010`. (I know, the OP has said: `less than`, but the sample value implies it should be 'less than or equal to'.) The 'then' `substring` should be `substring(codigo, 5, 5)`, and the 'else' one, `substring(codigo, 7, len(codigo) - 6)`.